# svg with input foreignobjects nested in a form

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got many input fields nested inside foreign objects, one input field per foreignObject actually. Can I nest the hole svg inside a form tag and get the data onclick?

```
<form>
  <svg>
   <foreignObject>
     <input />
   </foreignObject>
   <foreignObject>
     <input />
   </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?